# Call 7 zip from ssis

Tags: sql-server-2016

I have written a SSIS package to unzip all the zip files in a given folder using 7 zip. I have used a for each loop container and script task.

7 zip is installed on my laptop. In the script I have given the location of 7 zip executable on my laptop.

Package works fine.

When I deploy my package it doesn't work.

What is standard practise. Do I need to install 7 zip on the sql server where I am going to install this package.

How does it work with Github.

Regards
Raj

Comment: You need to install 7Zip on the machine(s) where the SSIS package runs.

Comment: Thanks Dan.  It works. When I execute the deployed package from the sql server, a windows pops up with parameters and value, when I click ok. Everything runs. Can yoy please help me how do I stop popping of that window.

Comment: Are you running `7z.exe`?